# Phone PIN visible to keen observers?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-8

I acquired a S8+ earlier this week. One thing I noticed is when I enter my PIN, the number will only vanish after I hit the next number in the sequence. At best, a keen observer will only see the last number. At worst, someone will get my PIN by watching over my shoulder, etc..

Is there a fix for this behavior on the phone?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @user452820, there is a security setting in settings for that.  Go to Settings > Lock screen and security > Other security settings and change the slider on `Make passwords visible`.

[image: IMG:]

The blue slider should be greyed out to stop it.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to your phone's setting then find security. In security section look for password, find "show password" and turn it off. Sorry if I didn't say the exact place because I don't know how settings look like in your phone. But it's android and it means it should be there.